# finding coordinate of closed angles in the frame of the video stream

Tags: python, opencv

My question is this. I have pictures of the card: [Unclosed card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6qmQ.jpg)

The corners of the card are not covered by anything, and I can use the findContours() function to detect them: [findContours Unclosed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em9CW.jpg)
But if a small part of the card is closed or the whole corner is closed, the detection of corners becomes an unreal task.
[Finger closed card1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMPyt.jpg) [findContours Closed1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3k9G.jpg) 
[Finger closed card2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8jAq.jpg) [findContours Closed2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWXxO.jpg) 
Is there a way to detect the corners of the card, even if they are closed?
I have a video stream, and I process each frame.

Comment: If one of the corners of the card is obscured you can use geometry to estimate the point of the corner

Comment: Can you tell me more?